# Angular $watch - execute watch block only once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I have a simple `$watch` on a `dropdown` value :

```
$scope.view;
$scope.$watch('view', function(){
  console.log(1);       
  // watch block
}
```

The value is chaining with `ng-model`:

```
<select ng-model="view" ng-options="x for x in name">
</select>
```

Due to the `$digest` the value 1 is printed twice, is there a way to tell angular to execute the the `$watch` block only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: unregister the watch after the first successful run:

```
var viewWatch = $scope.$watch('view', function () {
  viewWatch(); // Stops the watch
  console.log(1);       
  //watch block
};
```

However this may or may not yield the results you want, because sometime the `$watch` is called upon initialization. You may want to set some conditions:

```
var viewWatch = $scope.$watch('view', function (currentValue, oldValue) {
  if (currentValue && !oldValue) {
    viewWatch(); // Stops the watch
    console.log(1);       
    //watch block
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply test if `view` is about to be set for the first time (declared) or is about to be changed (by the select) by testing the params :

```
$scope.$watch('view'), function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (oldVal && oldVal != newVal) {
    console.log(1)
  }
}
```